# Missing scroll bar in Emacs 24

Tags: scrollbar, emacs24

The scroll bar in Emacs 24 is missing. `Scroll-Bar mode` is enabled.

Emacs 24 was installed from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cassou/+archive/emacs) and I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

I found a recommendation to [set `scroll-bar-mode`](https://superuser.com/questions/512332/my-emacs24-doesnt-have-scroll-bar) but mine is already set and does not produce the desired effect.

I [should be seeing GTK scroll bars](http://batsov.com/articles/2011/08/19/a-peek-at-emacs24/) but their absence seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/emacs24/+bug/1068373). One workaround suggested in a comment last year on the bug report is to launch Emacs as follows

```
LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 emacs24 &
```

which works for me. I am wondering if there is a fix from within Emacs by now.

Below is a screenshot of the problem. Note the missing scroll bar in the upper buffer and the information on the `scroll-bar-mode` variable and Emacs version in the lower ones.
[image: Emacs screen shot with missing scroll bar]

Comment: If you use emacs: 1. Why you still have X server installed ? 2. Why you still have mouse plugged in ? My suggestion: alias emacs="emacs -nw"

Comment: @Scony 1. I also use other applications. 2. The scroll bar gives me an indication of my location in the file. Do not worry, I am not using the mouse in Emacs!

Comment: 1. I dont understand what are 'other applications'. 2. Bottom emacs's bar (gray one) should tell you what line are you at and display what % of file this line is at. 3. God bless you ! Mouse programming is eclipse domain.

Comment: You are right. I had forgotten about the % indicator because of my habitual reliance on the scroll bar. It still would be nice to have the scroll bar back. It is after all a default feature.